# Search data using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have some documents structured like this:

```
{
    "_id": Mongoid,
    "relate_id": 1,
    "userid": user1
},
{
    "_id": Mongoid,
    "relate_id": 2,
    "userid": user2
},
{
    "_id": Mongoid,
    "relate_id": 1,
    "userid": user3
}
```

My expected result is below:

```
{
    "relate_id": 1
    "userid": [user1, user3]
},
{
    "relate_id": 2
    "userid": [user2]
}
```

Can I search this structure using one `aggregate()` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use the [group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) aggregation stage, using the [push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push) operator, to populate your list of userid

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: "$relate_id", userid: {"$push": "$userid"}}},
]
)
```